# String manipulation and Date format in PHP

Tags: php, explode, substr

I have a line in my code like this:

```
$folderTitle = displayName(getAlbumName($foo));
```

This would call the album's name in an image gallery.
The album's names are something like this

> 2017.03.14 Something Here

I need to show it like this:

> Something Here
> 14/03/2017

How to convert date format and rearrange lines order to follow my requirements?

Sorry but the answers bellow didn't make effect.

Comment: You've already named two possibilities.  Did you make an attempt with either?

Comment: Help with what? You haven't told us the issue with our code

Comment: or user `str_replace()` to change the dots for /. Or most likely, in the function displayName you can edit the way of displaying the data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name = "2017.03.14 Something Here";
echo substr($name, 10) . '<\br>'. str_replace(".", "/", substr($name, 0, 10));
```

something like this ?
(arround 1 min to write...)

if "2017.03.14 Something Here" is (displayName(getAlbumName($folder,$items[$i])).$fc

then :

```
$name = (displayName(getAlbumName($folder,$items[$i])).$fc;
$folderTitle = '<div class="imagetitle">'.substr($name, 10) . '<\br>'. str_replace(".", "/", substr($name, 0, 10)).'</div>';
```

wasn't hard to implement, sorry to be rude but seams that you don't do any effort

Comment: How can I use this in my code? Assuming the code I've posted.

Comment: replace $name by what you want here : displayName(getAlbumName($folder,$items[$i])).$fc if it display "2017.03.14 Something Here"

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb The error 500 is clearly not due of my/our code, check more about your  (displayName(getAlbumName($folder,$items[$i])) function while the functions use here (substr,str_replace) is internal to php

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb So the problem is in you code or you didn't tell all we needed to know to help you

Comment: for information, error 500 is about a file or an ajax request which you have the right URL or about your server which don't have a good configuration so the problem going more far than the original question

Comment: Ok, so thank you. You didn't need to give a -1 to my question. I'll quit with this issue and keep the old format.

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb i didn't give you a -1 actually but i think that you deserved it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your title is contained in a variable named `$title` :

```
echo substr($title, strpos($title, ' ') + 1), '<br>', str_replace('.', '/', substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' '))), '<br>';
```

This code prints the part of your string that is after the first space - identifiend with `strpos` - and prints it followed by a linebreak. It then prints the first part of the string - the date - after having replaced the dots in it with slashes.
I use `strpos()` to retrieve the breaking point between the two parts since dates can be displayed in different formats and years can be writtent with either 2 or 4 digits, and there is no point in being lazy so that the code gives shitty results in the future.

Comment: How can I use this in my code? Assuming the code I've posted.

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb Somewhat disappointed you didn't deem us worthy of writing personalized messages, especially lazy comments like that.

Comment: sorry but in both answers I didn't understant how to implement the code, so I asked the same on them.

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb I got that, it's just that both answers are pretty clear. Add that to the fact that your question didn't provide your tries, and you come up as afraid of doing stuff.

Comment: ok, I've tested and I got an error, maybe about syntax: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb If your code has other issues, please ask another question.